# Determine the series is conditionally or absolutely convergent.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

This is the problem:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-\frac{1}{2})^n$$

How can we decide the series is a conditionally or an absolutely convergent?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Please state your efforts so far and whether or not you can define the two types of convergence mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left|\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right|$ converge? If yes, then the series is absolutely convergent. If not, but the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ still converges, then it is conditionally convergent. If neither converge then the series is divergent.

Comment: I know this information but I need the solution.

Comment: @ArdaEremKaragoz We're here to help you get to the solution. First of all, can you simplify $\left|\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n\right|$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Actually I am on the last step, I don't know whether $$\lim_{x\to \infty}(\frac{1}{2})^n$$ is convergent or not, if it is, how?

Comment: @ArdaEremKaragoz Hint: it's a geometric series.

Comment: @ArdaEremKaragoz I don't think you want $\lim_{x\to \infty}$. But as Theo pointed out, this is a geometric series. So it converges if and only if the ratio is strictly between $-1$ and $1$.

Answer (score 0):

For $|x|<1$
$$\frac{1}{1+x}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-x)^n=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-x)^n$$